# How do i handle errors correctly and prevent showing folder directory

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo-server

I'm trying to create my own backend server from scratch using Apollo Server 2 for my school project and attempting to create a security features for authorisation and authentication but not sure if i should do it like this

I'm not quite sure if i handle the errors correctly for user Authorisation and when there's an error, the server will respond back an error with stacktrace including my folder directories of the server.

I have tried many ways and by far using try catch block minimise the errors i get.

### Auth.js /auth

```
import JWTR from 'jwt-redis'
import Redis from 'ioredis'

const redis = new Redis({
  ....
})

const jwtr = new JWTR(redis)
const token = req => req.headers.authorization.replace('Bearer', '').trim()
export const attemptSignIn = async (email, password) => {
    var user = await User.findOne({ email })

    if (!user || !await user.matchesPassword(password)) {
        throw new AuthenticationError(INVALID_CREDENTIAL)
}

const payload = await jwtr.sign({ id: user.id }, JWT_SECRET)
user.token = payload
return user
}

export const decodeAuthToken = async req => {
    if (!token(req)) {
        throw new AuthenticationError(NO_JWT)
    }
    try {
        const payload = await jwtr.verify(token(req), JWT_SECRET)
        return payload
    } catch (error) {
        throw new AuthenticationError(INVALID_JWT)
    }
}

export const checkAuthToken = async req => {
    console.log(token(req))
    if (!token(req)) {
        throw new AuthenticationError(NO_JWT)
    }
    try {
        const payload = await jwtr.verify(token(req), JWT_SECRET)
        if (payload) {
            return true
        }
    } catch (error) {
        throw new AuthenticationError(INVALID_JWT)
    }
    return false
}
```

### user.js /resolvers

```
import * as Auth from '../auth'
users: async (root, args, { req }, info) => {
    // Auth.checkSignedIn(req)
    await Auth.checkAuthToken(req)
    return User.find({})
},
```

Im expecting this error message but without getting this particular information in the error - > /Users/firmanjamal/Desktop/School Project/FYP/backend/src/auth.js:68:11)

```
"    at Proxy.checkAuthToken (/Users/firmanjamal/Desktop/School Project/FYP/backend/src/auth.js:68:11)",
        "    at process.internalTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:77:7)"

"errors": [
{
  "message": "The JWT you supply is not valid or already expired.",
  "locations": [
    {
      "line": 2,
      "column": 3
    }
  ],
  "path": [
    "user"
  ],
  "extensions": {
    "code": "UNAUTHENTICATED",
    "exception": {
      "stacktrace": [
        "AuthenticationError: The JWT you supply is not valid or already expired.",
        "    at Proxy.checkAuthToken (/Users/firmanjamal/Desktop/School Project/FYP/backend/src/auth.js:68:11)",
        "    at process.internalTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:77:7)"
      ]
    }
  }
}
],
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/features/errors.html):

> To disable stacktraces for production, pass debug: false to the Apollo server constructor or set the NODE_ENV environment variable to ‘production’ or ‘test’. Note that this will make the stacktrace unavailable to your application.

In other words, the stacktrack is included by default, but only when the NODE_ENV environment variable isn't set to `production`. If you want to omit the stacktrace, even in development, create your ApolloServer like this:

```
new ApolloServer({ typeDefs, resolvers, debug: false })
```